# HttpUrlConnection's response omits the word 'http'

Tags: java, http

I create the URL object using a string like `"http://www.example.com/a?s=12"`. I read the HTML response in the string `serverResponse`. This string is expected to have the entire HTML of a page, which has JavaScript and CSS includes. But strangely, the word "http:" is missing from all the URLs present in the response, eg in place of `"http://example.com"` I get `"//asd.com"`. Any ideas?

```
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer serverResponse = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        serverResponse.append(inputLine);
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    System.out.println(serverResponse);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here: [Protocol-relative URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator#Protocol-relative_URLs)

Answer (score 1):

> This string is expected to have the entire HTML of a page, which has javascript and CSS includes.

Why? A properly-constructed site will use relative URLs as much as possible. This seems to be one of them. Well done them, or you if it's your work.

> But strangely, the word "http:" is missing from all the URLs present in the response, eg in place of "http://example.com" I get "//asd.com". Any ideas?

It's called a protocol-relative URL.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the problem.

Comment: But when I query the same URL from the browser I get the complete HTML, with "http:". How is that possible?